# MouseDragElementBehavior Binding Properties

Tags: wpf, binding, properties, mouse, behavior

By default MouseDragElementBehavior does not implement the methods of Binding (SetBinding, GetBindingExpression, etc) how can I make a binding object to this behavior? Is this possible?

Comment: what do you mean with **make a binding object to this behavior**??

Comment: I have an object called "MyElementVisual" with the X and Y values​​, height, width, etc., would like the X and Y values ​​correspond to the value of behavior, because I use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if i understand your question, but something like this may work:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="MyVisualElement" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black" Height="90" Canvas.Left="188" Canvas.Top="113" Width="90">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ei:MouseDragElementBehavior x:Name="mouse" X="{Binding Height, ElementName=MyVisualElement}" Y="{Binding Width, ElementName=MyVisualElement}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Rectangle>
```

The MouseDragElementBehavior inerits from DependencyObject and you can set bindings to the properties X and Y, note in the previous code how the element name is specified.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, my english is sucks, thanks for the help, i was trying... and worked!